# Not able to access the WEB views using cleartool command

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I created a web view on a branch in Clear team explorer and i got all the elements to my local directory C:\Documents and settings\view1\vob\src.

Now the problem is i want find the labels and the last modified date of the elements present in the above directory.

i tried to use the cleartool command.

```
cleartool find C:\Documents and settings\view1\vob\src -type f -version "(lbtype(PROD))" -print
```

but i am getting the below error

```
cleartool: Error: Not an object in a vob: "C:\views\ac62599\AC62599_view\vob\".
cleartool: Warning: Skipping "C:\views\ac62599\AC62599_view\vob\".
```

i tried to start view also

```
cleartool startview view1
```

it also gave a error

```
cleartool: Error: View tag not found: "view1".
```

Please help me my requirement is to find the elements missing the label PROD and to find the elements merged to main branch on specified date i am using perl scripts for these requirements.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should execute a cleartool find within the view.

```
cd C:\Documents and settings\view1\vob\src
cleartool find . -type f -version "(lbtype(PROD))" -print
```

To get the name of the view:

```
cd  C:\Documents and settings\view1\vob\src
cleartool lsview -cview
```

Note that `cleartool` is available with a full ClearCase installation, and I doubt it is available with CCRC, the ClearCase Remote Client which uses [web views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.doc/topics/c_ccview.htm) (less sure with ClearTeam, which is [the new name for CCRC in v8](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.help.ic.doc/topics/c_whatsnew.htm) ).

Comment: the CLI is available with CCRC 7.0 as `rcleartool`. It might be available as `cleartool` with CCRC 8.0 or ClearTeam. The available commands are listed in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg24021929

Comment: I tried above approach also still i am not able to see my view and for label also i am getting the below error `cleartool: Error: Not an object in a vob: "." `

Comment: that to didnot worked actually in my machine i have both clearcase 7.0 and clearcase 8.0 the views created on old version are dynamic and the new version or web views if i am giving the above command it is displaying only the dynamic views created on the old clearcase not the new web views @VonC

Comment: @Ramesh So I confirm: cleartool is for CC7, not CC8 web views. You should use the rcleartool I mention in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg24021929

Comment: oh here comes another problem rcleartool needs seperate installation i guess because i am getting folowing error `'rcleartool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`. Any suggestions where can i get this package for installation.@VonC

Comment: @Ramesh the link I mention does describe how to install `rcleartool`